# scanner class package does not exist error

Tags: java

I was trying to compile a Java program, but it was generating an error.

Can someone tell me where I have made an error and how to fix it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class detail
{
String name;
int age;
float salary;
void getdata()
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter name: ");
    name=new sc.next();
    System.out.println("enter age: ");
    age=new sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter salary: ");
    salary=new sc.nextFloat();
}

void display()
{
    System.out.println("name: "+name);
    System.out.println("age: "+age);
    System.out.println("salary: "+salary);
}
}

class person
{
    public static void main(String arr[])
    {
        detail p=new detail();
        p.getdata();
        p.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 lines that contain

```
new sc
```

Remove `new` since `sc` is not a class, but a variable and you already created the `Scanner` object in this line:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
```

The `new` keyword is only allowed, if a constructor call follows or in java 8 in method references, which is not the case, if you type `new sc`.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to call `new sc.nextInt()`. You use "new" to create new objects. Your object `Scanner` is created by the variable `sc`, so you already can use their methods.

Like that:

```
age = sc.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the new from below lines and it will work

```
name=new sc.next();
System.out.println("enter age: ");
age=new sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("enter salary: ");
salary=new sc.nextFloat();
```

Comment: new is used in java to create an Object, and you have already created object named sc hence the use of 'new' with keyword was creating problem

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on lines like `name=new sc.next();`. You already used `new` to create an instance of `Scanner` called `sc`. You just need to call the instance methods on it:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class detail {
    String name;
    int age;
    float salary;

    void getdata() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter name: ");
        name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("enter age: ");
        age = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter salary: ");
        salary = sc.nextFloat();
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        System.out.println("age: " + age);
        System.out.println("salary: " + salary);
    }
}

class person {
    public static void main(String arr[]) {
        detail p = new detail();
        p.getdata();
        p.display();
    }
}
```

You do have a few other issues with your code, though, that are mainly stylistic:

```
// Java Code Conventions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html

// Removed import java.io.* because it wasn't used
import java.util.Scanner; // I prefer explicit imports, not *

class Detail { // Class names are typically uppercase
    // You don't have any visibility modifiers
    // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private float salary;

    // I would recommend a different name. Methods of the format
    // getX() usually indicate that they return a value. These are
    // called accessor methods
    public void getData() { // Method names are usually camel case
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter name: ");
        name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("enter age: ");
        age = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter salary: ");
        salary = sc.nextFloat();
        // You should close input methods
        sc.close();
    }

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        System.out.println("age: " + age);
        System.out.println("salary: " + salary);
    }
}

class Person { // Classes are usually uppercase names
    public static void main(String arr[]) {
        Detail p = new Detail();
        p.getData();
        p.display();
    }
}
```